# Looping transition and showing countries in a given order

Tags: d3.js

I'm using Mike Bostock World Tour Map [visualization](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4183330) and I'd like to make some modifications.

1) I'd like to replay the animation after the display of the last country.

2) Not sorted by name DESC, I'd like to define the order by the row number on the tsv file.

I've tried adding a replay function inside the transition but with no luck, I can't seem to really understand how it works so I need some help here.

```
function ready(error, world, names) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var globe = {type: "Sphere"},
      land = topojson.feature(world, world.objects.land),
      countries = topojson.feature(world, world.objects.countries).features,
      borders = topojson.mesh(world, world.objects.countries, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }),
      i = -1,
      n = countries.length;

  countries = countries.filter(function(d) {
    return names.some(function(n) {
      //if (d.id == n.id) return d.name = n.name;
      if (d.id == n.id) {
          d.name = n.name;
          d.org = n.org;
          return d;
      }
    });
  }).sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
  });

  (function transition() {
    d3.transition()
        .duration(1250)
        .each("start", function() {
          var data_pais = countries[i = (i + 1) % n]
          title.text(data_pais.name);
          subtitle.text(data_pais.org);
        })
        .tween("rotate", function() {
          var p = d3.geo.centroid(countries[i]),
              r = d3.interpolate(projection.rotate(), [-p[0], -p[1]]);
          return function(t) {
            projection.rotate(r(t));
            c.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
            c.fillStyle = "#ccc", c.beginPath(), path(land), c.fill();
            c.fillStyle = "#f00", c.beginPath(), path(countries[i]), c.fill();
            c.strokeStyle = "#fff", c.lineWidth = .5, c.beginPath(), path(borders), c.stroke();
            c.strokeStyle = "#000", c.lineWidth = 2, c.beginPath(), path(globe), c.stroke();
          };
        })
      .transition()
        .each("end", transition);
  })();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original code in the bl.ock actually repeats itself (I haven't actually seen this though). The country that is displayed is in the section:

```
title.text(countries[i = (i + 1) % n].name);
```

Which allows the list to repeat. However, n is defined by the number of geographic features rather than the number of entries in the TSV. Which is great if you want to visit every country, but less good if you want to visit some. So you can redefine n to be:

```
 n = names.length;
```

As for the sort, you should be able to lop off if you just want to remove the alphabetical sort.

```
 .sort(function(a, b) {
return a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
```

But, now the default display order will be the order of features within the world json. To change that, I tried applying an "order" column to the TSV and applied that value to the sort:

```
countries = countries.filter(function(d) {
return names.some(function(n) {
   if (d.id == n.id) { return  [d.order = n.order, d.name = n.name] }
   })
}).sort(function(a, b) {
   return +a.order - +b.order; 
});
```

This uses a TSV column named "order", though there would probably be more elegant approaches that use row number instead.

It is also important to note that the initial entries in the TSV, the ones marked with negative numbers, do not exist as features on the map, so it would be wise to not use them in any custom TSV.

I think the bl.ock referenced in the question might stop on Samoa, third from the end, as I had some difficulty with this entry testing this solution, removing it fixed that issue. It may not exist as a feature in the world json. So there may be some others that cause hiccups.

Example: [Custom World Tour (bl.ocks.org)](http://bl.ocks.org/andrew-reid/c4766786fa73ae25f926d1fba57050a8)

Comment: Hey Andrew, you were right about the names.length bit, thanks!. The custom sort didn't work, I remove the sort code and passed the tsv to a csv file just in case, but it shows the countries in alphabetic order anyway.

Comment: Ah, yeah, guess I should have swapped the order around while testing. I think I managed to address that; in a few limited tests I managed a custom order. I've updated the answer with some additional code.